# Weird Add Content problem?

Tags: 7, nodes, redirection

I have been dabbling with Drupal 7 and I am not quite sure what I did but turns out that after the interval of that mindless exploring, if I decide to add a specific Content type, it redirects me straight to only one content type (a custom content type I created using the Add Content type option) without consenting me on what kind of content type I specifically want.

I am not sure where I goofed up but does anybody know how the 'Add content' redirects you to a specific content type happen. Maybe I disabled the existing content types somehow, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: What other project modules are active on your site? The redirect could be coming from a module.  Also, are you using pathauto?  What is the path name for nodes of each content type?

Comment: Hi JoeS, I did not enable/disable a module on my site today, was simply dabbling with some menu bar configs for specific content types, thanks

Comment: Also, if I specify through the URL's such as :
node/add/basic or node/add/article it redirects me to the basic page/ article content type

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at Content > Content Types.  If there is only one content type listed on this page, then it means you probably deleted all other content types.  This may be your problem.

Comment: I don't think I have deleted my existing content types Ben, It redirects itself to the content type I added without asking me what content type I am trying to create.

Comment: I've never seen that.  So I was thinking maybe you disabled or deleted all but one, so it's just skipping the step where you can choose it.  Did you go to `admin > content > content types` ?

Comment: Yes, pretty much went to Admin > content > content-types....Do you know how we can enable/disable content typeS?

Comment: they are definitely not deleted, because if i visit admin > structure > content types, I see all the content types listed

Comment: I don't have a clue then.  Sorry. I'm pretty new at Drupal myself.

Answer (score 1):

Check your "add content" links in the navigation menu (admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation/list). Make sure all of the links to your content types are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Steve's answer, you should also check that the links for creating content of each type are nested under the "Add content" link in the "Navigation" menu. If there is only one menu link nested under "Add content" it will automatically redirect to that content type's creation form when you click the "Add content" link. After a standard install (which create's two content types) your Navigation menu structure should look like the screenshot below. Check your site's menu against that.

[image]